# Is there a FindHDF4.cmake package which finds HDF4 libraries that weren't installed by cmake?

Tags: cmake, hdf

I need to find the HDF4 library for a CMake build.

I have a FindHDF4.cmake which finds HDF4 if it was installed by CMake. But usually HDF4 isn't installed with CMake. Usually it is installed with autotools, the standard GNU install pacakge.

Does anyone have a FindHDF4.cmake which works on all HDF4 installs? (Including installs of HDF4 in which cmake was not used - i.e. installs with configure/make instead of installs with cmake.)

Here is the FindHDF4 script that I have:

```
#
# To be used by projects that make use of CMakeified hdf-4.2.5
#

#
# Find the HDF4 includes and get all installed hdf4 library settings from
# HDF4-config.cmake file : Requires a CMake compatible hdf-4.2.6 or later 
# for this feature to work. The following vars are set if hdf4 is found.
#
# HDF4_FOUND               - True if found, otherwise all other vars are undefined
# HDF4_INCLUDE_DIR         - The include dir for main *.h files
# HDF4_FORTRAN_INCLUDE_DIR - The include dir for fortran modules and headers
# HDF4_VERSION_STRING      - full version (e.g. 4.2.5)
# HDF4_VERSION_MAJOR       - major part of version (e.g. 4.2)
# HDF4_VERSION_MINOR       - minor part (e.g. 5)
# 
# The following boolean vars will be defined
# HDF4_ENABLE_PARALLEL - 1 if HDF4 parallel supported
# HDF4_BUILD_FORTRAN   - 1 if HDF4 was compiled with fortran on
# HDF4_BUILD_CPP_LIB   - 1 if HDF4 was compiled with cpp on
# HDF4_BUILD_TOOLS     - 1 if HDF4 was compiled with tools on
# 
# Target names that are valid (depending on enabled options)
# will be the following
#
# hdf              : HDF4 C library
# hdf_f90cstub     : used by Fortran to C interface
# hdf_fortran      : Fortran HDF4 library
# mfhdf            : HDF4 multi-file C interface library
# xdr              : RPC library
# mfhdf_f90cstub   : used by Fortran to C interface to multi-file library
# mfhdf_fortran    : Fortran multi-file library
# 
# To aid in finding HDF4 as part of a subproject set
# HDF4_ROOT_DIR_HINT to the location where hdf4-config.cmake lies

INCLUDE (SelectLibraryConfigurations)
INCLUDE (FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

# The HINTS option should only be used for values computed from the system.
SET (_HDF4_HINTS
    $ENV{HOME}/.local
    $ENV{HDF4_ROOT}
    $ENV{HDF4_ROOT_DIR_HINT}
)
# Hard-coded guesses should still go in PATHS. This ensures that the user
# environment can always override hard guesses.
SET (_HDF4_PATHS
    $ENV{HOME}/.local
    $ENV{HDF4_ROOT}
    $ENV{HDF4_ROOT_DIR_HINT}
    /usr/lib/hdf
    /usr/share/hdf
    /usr/local/hdf
    /usr/local/hdf/share
)

FIND_PATH (HDF4_ROOT_DIR "hdf4-config.cmake"
    HINTS ${_HDF4_HINTS}
    PATHS ${_HDF4_PATHS}
    PATH_SUFFIXES
        lib/cmake/hdf4
        share/cmake/hdf4
)

FIND_PATH (HDF4_INCLUDE_DIRS "hdf.h"
    HINTS ${_HDF4_HINTS}
    PATHS ${_HDF4_PATHS}
    PATH_SUFFIXES
        include
        Include
)

# For backwards compatibility we set HDF4_INCLUDE_DIR to the value of
# HDF4_INCLUDE_DIRS
SET ( HDF4_INCLUDE_DIR "${HDF4_INCLUDE_DIRS}" )

IF (HDF4_INCLUDE_DIR)
  INCLUDE (${HDF4_ROOT_DIR}/hdf4-config.cmake)
ENDIF (HDF4_INCLUDE_DIR)

# handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set HDF4_FOUND to TRUE if
# all listed variables are TRUE
INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(HDF4 REQUIRED_VARS HDF4_LIBRARIES HDF4_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

Comment: "I have a FindHDF4.cmake which finds HDF4 if it was installed by CMake" - Eh? "Find" scripts doesn't require installation to be performed with CMake. Unless those scripts calls `find_package` themselves. "... works on all HDF4 installs?" - What do you mean by "all installs"? Each file from the package being installed to any location? No one `Find` script can handle that. Your question is quite **unclear**: We don't know which exact `FindHDF4.cmake` script do you use, which exact installation it cannot handle and which other installations you want to process.

Comment: I'm trying to do in CMake what can be done in one line in autoconf: AC_SEARCH_LIBS([SDcreate], [mfhdf], [USE_HDF4=yes], [USE_HDF4=no])

Comment: It seems that both you questions (this one and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995928/does-cmake-have-a-standard-way-of-finding-libraries-like-the-netcdf-c-library)) are actually "What is an analogue of AC_SEARCH_LIBS in CMake". You incorrectly treat `find_package` to be such analogue, but it is not. Actually. the mostly similar thing is [check_function_exists](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckFunctionExists.html). See e.g. [thas mailing](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-September/055737.html).

Comment: But note that CMake has a different view of a library to link with than Autotools has. While Autotools **checks** the library just by function in it, CMake **searches** the library file by its name (with `find_library`) and **searches** the **include directory** by the header file name (with `find_path`). Command `find_package` is for "complex" libraries, which could contain from multiple library files and include directories, which could have different configurations and versions and many other properties.